# Docker NGINX won't serve two sites

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm using Docker for the first time, trying to build an NGINX proxy (also first time with NGINX). I've seen multiple guides that all seem to suggest I'm on the right path, but when I run the image, I get `duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf`.

site.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name gamersplane.local;
    root /var/www;
    index dispatch.php;

    location / {
         try_files $uri /dispatch.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /dispatch.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index dispatch.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

api.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name api.gamersplane.local;
    root /var/www/api;
    index dispatch.php;

    location / {
         try_files $uri /dispatch.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /dispatch.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index dispatch.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have two compose files:

docker-compose.yal

```
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: gamersplane-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
```

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
  proxy:
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/dev/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
      - ./nginx/dev/api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/api.conf
```

Comment: have you tested my answer below ?

Comment: Sorry, got to try it last night, and it did work. I just didn't get to post while at work today.

Comment: never mind, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `ipv6_only=on`, according to the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

> This parameter is turned on by default. It can only be set once on start.

So no need to add it to your config